# Automatic binding does not work for caliburn.micro in View First (WPF)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, caliburn.micro

I have a problem with automatic bindings (conventions) which should work by default in caliburn.micro. I use WPF with MVVM (also Fody.PropertyChanged, SimpleInjector, Visual Studio 2015). Mainly I use ViewModel-first approach (for example for MainView). And for this case everything works fine - textbox has automatic binding to the property in VM, label and button the same.

But problem occured when I've added new User Control (named "TestView") with View-first approach. I've added code-behind with InitializeComponent in constructor because user control wasn't rendered previously.
I've applied everything from this link ("View First"): https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=All%20About%20Actions
(I left unmodified only MefBootstrapper.OnStartup - in my case AppBootstrapper.OnStartup)

I've:
 1. added `[Export("TestViewModel", typeof(TestViewModel))]` to my VM
 2. added to my View
 `xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
 cal:Bind.Model="TestViewModel"`

DataContext for View is set correctly. If I add bindings manually then everything works fine - but this should be done automatically by caliburn.micro (like for ViewModel-first).

[image: works fine for manual bindings - image]

Am I wrong? Or do I have to manually set bindings for View-first? Or did I forget about something? Or maybe some changes were .net and caliburn.micro is outdated...

Below full code (MainView is made with ViewModel-first, TestView with View-first):
https://github.com/Krzyrok/caliburn.micro-problem

PS (side notes/question/clarification)
I know that more popular is ViewModel-first approach and I can change my UserControl to this (and autobindings will work again). And question is not about this but below is my motivation (maybe another approach is suggested in WPF):
I chose this solution because I wanted "closed" component (similar to the splitting components on frontend with e.g. React) - I wanted to use a "complete" component/UserControl which I can use on MainView without declaring any additional VM in MainVM. In my case TestView knows exactly what VM should be used so there is no reason to force me/another programmer to declare also VM - it needs only View which he will use in the future (VM is "technical details/implementation" of logic). But: is there another approach for splitting view to smaller "components"/sections in WPF (suggested one)? I searched and UserControl seems to meet the assumptions.
Edit: By "component/section" I mean some portion of View ([composition of] few controls responsible e.g. for displaying/editing user details).
This is only side note/question so focus on the main question, please :)

Comment: In terms of clarification: The way I would achieve this (splitting views into components essentially), would be to use controls (not user controls).
Controls could achieve what you are wanting without the need for view models. In this case you create the variables and the logic within a class, and then implement the look via styles. This way you can link your ViewModel to the control on top level. Look at following for tutorial for implementing this: https://www.wpftutorial.net/HowToCreateACustomControl.html
Note; not posted as answer as doesn't answer given question.

Comment: @DHansen As I understand, Custom Control are for overriding control/creating new one. But only for one "small control" (e.g. in library with controls).  
And User Control can encapsulate some composition of controls (e.g. form) - rather section of UI than specific one small control.  
https://www.wpftutorial.net/CustomVsUserControl.html  
I would second one in my case (extracting independent sections of view - which can be used on another view).  
But this shows me that WPF has many options, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

Automatically searching the IoC container by supplying a string is **not supported any more** since v3. The feature has only been partially removed, what makes it even more confusing, and it's still referenced in the documentation. I created an issue to address this.

You can work around this by calling the IoC by yourself. I would recommend using a value provider, like this:

```
public class IoCExtension : MarkupExtension
{
    private readonly string key;

    public IoCExtension(string key)
    {
        this.key = key;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return IoC.GetInstance(null, this.key);
    }
}
```

And use it in your view like this:

```
xmlns:t="clr-namespace:TestingCaliburnMicro"
cal:Bind.Model="{t:IoC TestViewModel}"
```

This way, you can easily replace the resolution logic with your own, if the static IoC class disappears some day.

The commits and issues:

- [IoC depreciation log message](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/commit/09bd5cb77f4a1aef8f8e024ba774851cf9c4b6de#diff-393f9781e9c0dc7ce1b57946e58795e8)
- [Feature removal](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/commit/54c1ad299b0f4e060ae621bf130ce531117857f2#diff-393f9781e9c0dc7ce1b57946e58795e8)
- [Discussion](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/331)
- [Issue](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/481)

There is another attached property in the `Bind` class, named `Bind.ModelWithoutContext`. Even there, the IoC call is still there.